# How to group routes by domain in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Iam using Route::group to group route by domain

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'user.domain.local'], function() {

});
```

When I access user.domain.local/abc/, everything is ok.

But when I access www.user.doamin.local/abc/, Laravel throw HttpNotFoundException. I want to it same as when access user.domain.local/abc/

How do I fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 5.3 - oldest**

```
Route::pattern('user_subdomain', '(www.user|user)');

Route::group(['domain' => '{user_subdomain}.domain.local'], function ()
{
    ....
});
```

**Laravel 5.4 - newest**

```
Route::pattern('user_subdomain', '(www.user|user)');

Route::domain('{user_subdomain}.domain.local')->group(function ()
{
    ....
});
```

Comment: Iam using Laravel 5.4. But laravel throw error: `UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: ...`

Comment: Show your complete route! The error isn't caused by this code. Try commenting the other code, then reserve this code.

Comment: thanks for responsing ! After use your code, when I call `route('bookmarked')` then Laravel throw `UrlGenerationException Missing required parameters for [Route: ...'`. But if I code `'route('bookmarked', ['www' => 'www'])` then everything is Ok. So I write your code: `Route::domain('{user_subdomain?}.domain.local')->group(function ()
{
    ....
});` Then Everything is OK. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Laravel `Subdomain routing` is the same as route `prefixing`, but it’s scoped by `subdomain` instead of route `prefix`. In laravel, we can create features using `Routing subdomain`. Syntax essentially as follows:

```
Route::pattern('www', '(www|)');

Route::group(['domain' => '{www}.user.domain.local'], function() {

});
```

Comment: Oh! I missed the pattern part

Comment: thanks for responsing ! But Laravel throw `UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: ...` .

Comment: update question and show your URL for which it shows error

Comment: thanks for responsing ! After use your code, when I call `route('bookmarked')` then Laravel throw `UrlGenerationException Missing required parameters for [Route: ...'. But if I code 'route('bookmarked', ['www' => 'www'])` then everything is Ok. So I write your code: 
`Route::group(['domain' => '{www?}.user.domain.local'], function() {

});`
Then Everything is OK.
Thanks again

Comment: which version of laravel are you using??  It's working fine on my own project.

Comment: Iam using Laravel 5.4. With your code, everything is ok. But when I want to render a route in blade, I must add param 'www' because if don't have this param, Laravel will throw `UrlGenerationException`. Ex: `route('bookmarked', ['www' => 'www'])`.